# Sourcemaps breaks for console.log in node_modules in webpack and babel build

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, source-maps

I'm trying to enable sourcemaps for my Babel 7.7 and Webpack 4.41 built code.

The sourcemaps work fine except for console statements that originate from code in node_modules. These statements are mostly dev hints, warnings for when we do something wrong. For console statements in our own source code the sourcemaps work, they also work if an error occurs in the 3rd party lib.

When a dependency console.logs the trace looks like this:

```
Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object String]
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/app/bootstrap/bootstrap.js:66:13)
From previous event:
    at _callee$ (webpack-internal:///./src/app/bootstrap/bootstrap.js:65:140)
    at tryCatch (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
```

When inspecting bootstrap.js in the browser I don't exactly get the build code, a sourcemap is still applied, but I also don't get the output from babel, even less the original code. It's some state in between.

I've created a simple repo where the issue is reproduced, to try to solve it in a controlled manner: https://github.com/pstenstrm/webpack-sourcemap-test

```
Object(react_loadable__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9__["preloadReady"])().then(function _callee() {
  return _Users_path_to_proj_node_modules_babel_runtime_corejs3_regenerator__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.async(function _callee$(_context) {
    while (1) {
      switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
        case 0:
          _context.next = 2;
          return _Users_path_to_proj_node_modules_babel_runtime_corejs3_regenerator__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.awrap(new bluebird__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a(function (a, reject) {
            reject('asdas');
          }));
```

My babel config looks like this:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                targets: {
                    browsers: "last 2 versions"
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
            {
                "corejs": 3,
                "proposals": true,
                "absoluteRuntime": true
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

In webpack the setup looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./src/index.js'],
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: [/node_modules/],
            use: 'babel-loader?sourceMap&cacheDirectory'
        }]
    },
};
```

I've tested all options for https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/, while some options made it marginally worse no option made it better.

I've also tried to configure `SourceMapDevToolPlugin` and `EvalSourceMapDevToolPlugin` to solve the issue but again no improvement. I might be missing something but I don't know what it might be.

Is this expected, is console.log in node_modules simply not supported, or is there a setting I'm missing?

Comment: Try one of webpack config generators online - there are already a lot of them maybe they will help you. console.log is supported. If your loaders /  babel does the job before source-map generates you don't get original code in output map. Check also https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/ to pick right source-map for you.

Comment: @Zydnar I can't find any help from generators. I will try to dig deeper into devtool and to use the plugin instead of the devtool property. I've added a repo where the issue is reproduced.

Comment: @pstenstrm please see https://github.com/pstenstrm/webpack-sourcemap-test/issues/1

Comment: I also am unable to reproduce the problem.